# Threads to remove items from a Queue in C

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I just want to add items to a Queue, and a thread to remove them when something is in the queue. I was going with the approach of taking something off the stack and then just waiting like 10 seconds, then doing it again. Im just not sure how to approach throwing it into the thread. Im using C on PuTTy. I have the functions defied. didnt want to copy thme over to save space. delete() just remove the first one in. How would I have the Thread pause for 10 seconds. Sleep actually pauses the command window.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <conio.h>

#define MAXQUEUE 100

    struct queue 
    {
        char name[256];
        struct queue *link;
    };

void *thread_routine(void *arg) {
    int tr;
    while(tr!=0) {
        sleep(10);
        delete();
    }

}

struct queue *start=NULL;

int i=0;

void main() {

    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    void *thread_result;
    int status;
    status = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_routine, NULL);
    if (status != 0) {
        printf ("thread create failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* wait for the thread to finish */

    status = pthread_join(thread1, &thread_result);
    if (status != 0) {
        printf ("thread join failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf ("child thread finished: result = %d\n", (int) thread_result);

    int ch;
    while(ch!=4) {
        printf("\nSelect an option:\n");
        printf("1 to add an item to the queue\n");
        //printf("2 to delete an item from the queue\n");
        printf("3 to print the queue\n");
        printf("4 for Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch) {
            case 1: 
                add();
                break;
            case 2: 
                delete();
                break;
            case 3: 
                print();
                break;
            case 4: 

                break;
            default:
                printf("Incorrect option\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using the `delete` identifier, since it is a reserved C++ keyword.

Answer (score 1):

> Sleep actually pauses the command window.

That's because you joined the thread aka wait for it to finish.  Leave the thread detached and perhaps make an infinite loop for reading options.

Also, I would suggest using a mutex and condition variable for notifying the thread of when a new item gets inserted.  Doing it the "sleep" way should work though but it probably won't *immediately* delete the item as you expect.

Comment: what do u mean detached? Someone else also said a mutex.

Comment: "Detached" just as if it is running in the background (so it's not joined with the main() thread, or simply as if it was a daemon)

Comment: Why would I want to detach a thread? Does it run in the background?

Comment: It does not run in your desktop background....  it just runs independetly so it'd go like this:
Main Thread -- running fine, nothing blocking it from doing work.
Deletion Thread - working fine as well.
So Deletion Thread would run completely outside the main function (in another context) where it would execute stuff normally

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a alarm signal instead of `sleep().` just set a handler for the signal and make sure no thread block it.

Comment: Signals are tricky with threads, so I won't use this approach.